# NRF52 developing without using device trees

Tags: visual-studio-code, device-tree, nrf52, nrf-connect

I have recently picked up NRF52DK development board with NRF52832
https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-hardware/nrf52-dk

I have setup my development environment using VSCode NRF Connect extension.

I have been reading and learning a little bit about the NRF52 and realized that all the example projects use device trees.

For example, the code to toggle the GPIO:

```
#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <zephyr/device.h>
#include <zephyr/devicetree.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>

#define LED0_NODE DT_ALIAS(led0) // LED0_NODE = led0 defined in the .dts file

int main(void)
{
    static const struct gpio_dt_spec led = GPIO_DT_SPEC_GET(LED0_NODE, gpios);

    if (!device_is_ready(led.port))
    {
        return;
    }
    int ret;

    ret = gpio_pin_configure_dt(&led, GPIO_OUTPUT_ACTIVE);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    printf("Hello World! %s\n", CONFIG_BOARD);
    k_sleep(K_MSEC(1000));
    printf("Bye World! %s\n", CONFIG_BOARD);

    while (1)
    {
        ret = gpio_pin_toggle_dt(&led);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        k_msleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I dont like device trees at all and I have a couple of questions:

1. wonder if there is a way to write code without using device trees at all? Could you please provide GPIO initialization and toggling example code without using device trees as I could not find a single example without device trees at all.
2. device tree relies on having the `dts` as described here:
   [image]

What if I have my own custom nrf52 board and not a development board. Would I need to define my own device tree?

Answer (score 0):

Device trees are used by the Zephyr framework. Other frameworks don't use them.

Alternatives you could look into are:

- [Mbed](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/Nordic-nRF52-DK/)
- [libopencm3](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3)
- Arduino framework with [nRF52 Ardunio Core](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_nRF52_Arduino)

Answer (score 0):

Although I would HIGHLY recommend learning and embracing the use of Zephyr and its devicetrees, You can look into these alternatives.

- You can use the framework Nordic had before adapting Zephyr and nRF Connect SDK, called the [nRF5 SDK](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-software/nrf5-sdk), combined with their [nrfx drivers](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/nrfx). This is, as far as I know, completely baremetal.
- You can work around the devicetrees while still making your application on Zephyr by using the [nrfx drivers](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/nrfx), because they are available in the nRF Connect SDK.
- You can write your own drivers or use 3rd party drivers for stuff.

Comment: If you have a custom nrf52 board and not a development board, you can either make your own devicetree file (very difficult), or you can use the devicetree overlay files to overwrite and extend the default devicetree. I think Nordic has some tutorials on how to write overlays.